# Problem on installing dlib on windows 10(Cmake installed)

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, dlib

When I am trying to install dlib on my PC(windows 10, Pycharm) I am facing error about:

```
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown

  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
```

**What can I do about this?**

Comment: You need to have your *Visual Studio (VC)* (binaries) installation path in your *%PATH%* variable.

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Visual Studio. Below are the installation details. After the VS installation, dlib was installed successfully. Probably it needs the Linux development with C++ packet in order to work.
[image: VS installation details]